# How can I create nested resources in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I would like to first create a Digital Ocean droplet(server) and then create multiple docker containers for various services inside that server.

I feel like this should be easy but I cannot find any examples of others doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really nest resources like that in Terraform. You have a two different ways to approach this, I would use the [user_data](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/do/r/droplet.html#user_data) argument that will run a script on your droplet that will issue the docker commands to pull down your container images and start your containers. [Here](https://blog.digitalocean.com/automating-application-deployments-with-user-data/) is a blog post with an example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the answer. Thanks Jamie.